Can't deploy a contract on infura - ECONNTIMEDOUT
I'm getting ECONNTIMEDOUT error while deploying a contract. My internet is fine, the infura URL is correct, mnemonic is correct. The problem appears on Contract creation, so I got the list of accounts successfully. My code:
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    '...',
    'https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/...',
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
        .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};

deploy();

